# How to get source of php file by php?

Tags: php, jquery

I want the source code of a php file.I tried .load() method in jquery but it loads content of file but I want source code.How to do this with jQuery.

Comment: You cannot, getting the source code of a PHP file from a client side language would be a massive security risk.

Comment: You can't. PHP is pre-processed.

Comment: Unless the server you are pulling it from isn't processing the PHP code then you could get it. But that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: Your web server would have to return the unprocessed PHP code.  Which, unless you *really* know what you're doing, is a *famously* bad idea.

Comment: Why would you want the source of a PHP file? What use would that be to JavaScript?

Comment: I just reread the question are you saying it is returning the actual PHP code and you want the HTML source code it is suppose to generate? Or the other way around?

Comment: then how to get source code of php file by php?

Comment: You can't get someone else's PHP source code unless you have access to the file before it is processed by a browser. Read up on client/server architecture.

Comment: I want to access to my own PHP source code but from front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible.

If it was anyone could write a JavaSCript (because it is client side) and get content of any of your PHP scripts.